# tf.keras.models.save_model and optimizer warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, machine-learning, keras

I created a **Sequential** model using `tf.keras` as follows:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_dim=4))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()
```

After that, I created a training process using `train_on_batch`:

```
EPOCHS=50
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  for metrics, labels in dataset:
    # Calculate training loss and accuracy
    tr_loss, tr_accuracy = model.train_on_batch(metrics, labels)
```

When I try to save the model, I receive a warning. I can't understand why, because I included the optimizer as part of the `model.compile`:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model,
    "./model/iris_model.h5",
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True
)
```

> WARNING:tensorflow:TensorFlow optimizers do not make it possible to access optimizer attributes or optimizer state after instantiation. As a result, we cannot save the optimizer as part of the model save file.You will have to compile your model again after loading it. Prefer using a Keras optimizer instead (see keras.io/optimizers).

The TF version I used is 1.9.0-rc2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the warning says the Tensorflow optimizers cannot be saved when saving the model. Instead, use the [optimizers provided by Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/):

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
```

Comment: Yes, @today  you are right I changed the optimizer to allow the eager execution :(

Answer (score 1):

Optimizer like `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()` will be saved, and `tf.train.AdamOptimizer()` will not be saved on `model.save()`.

As the time as writing this some official tutorials on TensorFlow use `tf.train.*` optimizer while I strongly believe selecting the `tf.keras.optimizers.*` is the best way to go.